# How to access scoped keyframes from JS

Tags: css, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a scoped "keyframes" named move-left, I have to access it in JS, but HOW?
I tried to remove the scoped in , it will work, but I want it to be scoped, How can I access it 
you know, vue-loader will add random hash to move-left, something like move-left-xxxxxxxxx

```
<template>
  <div :style="{animation: animation}"></div>
</template>

<script>
      this.animation = "move-left linear 10s"  /// how to access move-left here
</script>
```

```
<style scoped>
  @keyframes move-left {
    from {
      transform: translateX(100vw);
    }
    to{
      transform: translateX(-150vw);
    }
  }
</style>
```

Comment: it can be achieved using CSS module. see `App.vue` in https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-nlizo

Comment: @JacobGoh So I need to use CSS module instead of scoped CSS, right?

Comment: yes. you can use multiple `<style>` blocks in one component if you want to use Scoped CSS for something else.

Comment: @JacobGoh Thank you! please post an answer so I can ACCEPT you

Comment: I can't .. lol.. this question is not opened... it's alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it can be achieved using CSS module. see App.vue in https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-nlizo

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div :style="{animation: animation}">123</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return { animation: `${this.$style["move-left"]} linear 10s` };
  }
};
</script>

<style module>
@keyframes move-left {
  from {
    transform: translateX(100vw);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(-150vw);
  }
}
</style>
```